# VB link SQL server problems

Tags: vb.net

I received a error as following:

> Conversion from type 'SqlConnection' to type 'String' is not valid.

My VB coding is :

```
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sSQL As String = String.Empty
    Try
        conn = New SqlConnection(Get_Constring)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        sSQL = "SELECT * FROM HostTable"
        If Me.cboSearchBy.Text = "Name" Then
            sSQL = sSQL & " where HOSTNAME like '%" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "%'"
        ElseIf Me.cboSearchBy.Text = "Function" Then
            sSQL = sSQL & " where FUCTION like '%" & Me.txtSearch.Text & "%'"
        End If
        cmd.CommandText = sSQL
        da.SelectCommand = cmd
        da.Fill(dt)

        Me.dtgResult.DataSource = dt
        If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            MsgBox("No record found!")
        End If
Function Get_Constring()
    If Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(Application.StartupPath, 1) = "\" Then
        sConnstring = New SqlConnection("server=192.168.1.111\SQLSERVER;database=Common_DB;User ID=sa;Password=12345678")
    Else
        sConnstring = New SqlConnection("server=192.168.1.111\SQLSERVER;database=Common_DB;User ID=sa;Password=12345678")
    End If
    Return sConnstring
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter you have hardcoded inside `New SqlConnection` is the actual Connection String.

You may want to write something like:

```
sConnstring = "server=192.168.1.111\SQLSERVER;database=Common_DB;User ID=sa;Password=12345678"
myConnection = New SqlConnection(sConnstring)
```

So your function `Get_Constring` should just return the string, not an entire connection.

```
Function Get_Constring()
If Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(Application.StartupPath, 1) = "\" Then
    sConnstring = "server=192.168.1.111\SQLSERVER;database=Common_DB;User ID=sa;Password=12345678"
Else
    sConnstring = "server=192.168.1.111\SQLSERVER;database=Common_DB;User ID=sa;Password=12345678"
End If
Return sConnstring
```

This should work as intended.

Comment: Also, consider turning in Option Strict - strongly type your returns and declare variables explicitly. Or just use `Return "server=192.168.1.111\SQLSERVER;database=Common_DB;User ID=sa;Password=12345678"` and dispense with the variable altogether.

Answer (score 0):

> Conversion from type 'SqlConnection' to type 'String' is not valid.

This error message is very clear. You cannot convert a (new) SqlConnection to a string (sConnstring).